# Close React Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm having a lot of problems trying to figure out how to add a functioning close button to my modal - constructor/props hasn't been working and I'm not sure what to put after onClick= in the button element.

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {

// whenever component gets rendered to the screen we create a new div assigned to this.modalTarget
 componentDidMount() {
  this.modalTarget = document.createElement('div');
  // add class name to modal target
  this.modalTarget.className = 'modal';
  // take the div we just created and append it to the body tag in doc
  document.body.appendChild(this.modalTarget);
  // call method _render
  this._render();
 }

// whenever the component's about to update we do another render
// this render makes sure that if we get a new set of components or children in the modal
// we're going to render those to the parent div as well
 componentWillUpdate() {
  this._render();
 }

// clean up - whenever the component is about to unmount from the screen
// cleans up dom when the modal is removed from the component heirarchy
 componentWillUnmount() {
  // unmounts this.props.children
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.modalTarget);
  document.body.removeChild(this.modalTarget);
 }

 _render() {
  // take react dom library and render a div that contains this.props.children
  // and render it into this.modalTarget
  ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store= {store}>
    <Router>
     <div className="modal">
      {this.props.children}
      <button>Close</button>
     </div>
    </Router>
   </Provider>,
   this.modalTarget
```

Comment: You might find it interesting to have a look at React's Portals API, it's intended for this kind of usage: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several issues here. First, move away from directly manipulating the `DOM`. React uses a virtual `DOM`, so you don't need to manually add or remove `DOM` elements. React automatically handles this `DOM` manipulation through the `render` method. 
Also, you'll need to control this `Modal` utilizing some sort of `state` (isOpen). It be can through React's local state or through Redux's state. Either way, it needs to be controlled and compared against. Put simply, if it's open, render the `Modal`, if it's closed, render `null`.

In addition, this `Modal` component can be structured to be reusable. Simply add it as a `child` to another stateful `parent` component and include whatever `children` you want to render inside of it.

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Simple Modal]

---

**components/Example.js** (parent component)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import "./styles.css";

class Example extends Component {
  state = { isOpen: false };

  handleOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="example">
      <h2>Simple Modal Example</h2>
      <button
        className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small"
        onClick={this.handleOpenModal}
      >
        Open Modal
      </button>
      <Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen} onCloseModal={this.handleCloseModal}>
        <h1 className="title">Hello!</h1>
        <p className="subtitle">There are two ways to close this modal</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Click outside of this modal in the grey overlay area.</li>
          <li>Click the close button below.</li>
        </ul>
        <button
          className="uk-button uk-button-danger uk-button-small"
          onClick={this.handleCloseModal}
        >
          Close
        </button>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

**components/Modal.js** (child component -- this has a lot of smaller components that were separated for reusability and ease of understanding -- they're basically simple `div`s with some `styles` attached -- see notes below)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import BackgroundOverlay from "../BackgroundOverlay"; // grey background
import ClickHandler from "../ClickHandler"; // handles clicks outside of the modal
import Container from "../Container"; // contains the modal and background
import Content from "../Content"; // renders the "children" placed inside of <Modal>...</Modal>
import ModalContainer from "../ModalContainer"; // places the modal in the center of the page

// this is a ternary operator (shorthand for "if/else" -- if cond ? then : else)
// below can be read like: if isOpen is true, then return/render the modal, else return null
const Modal = ({ children, isOpen, onCloseModal }) =>
  isOpen ? (
    <Container>
      <BackgroundOverlay />
      <ModalContainer>
        <ClickHandler isOpen={isOpen} closeModal={onCloseModal}>
          <Content>{children}</Content>
        </ClickHandler>
      </ModalContainer>
    </Container>
  ) : null;

// these proptype declarations are to ensure that passed down props are 
// consistent and are defined as expected
Modal.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired, // children must be a React node
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired, // isOpen must be a boolean
  onCloseModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired // onCloseModal must be a function
};

export default Modal;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your modal is open based simply on whether it's rendered by the parent. Short of all together reengineering this pattern, the only way to achieve what you want would be to pass in a callback:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { isModalOpen: false };

  render() {
    return (<div>
      // Stuff
      {this.state.isModalOpen &&
        <Modal onClose={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })}/>
      }
      // Stuff
    </div>);
  }
}
```

In your `Modal`:

```
<div className="modal">
    {this.props.children}
    <button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS Modal Close button with the following example

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
const App = () => {

const { useState} = React;
const [showmodal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

const handlemodal = () => {

    setShowModal(true);
}

const closeModal = () => {

    setShowModal(false);
}
return (

    <>
        <div className={`overlay ${!showmodal?`overlay-none`:``}`}>
            <div className="content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    <span>Save changes</span>
                    <i onClick={closeModal} class="mdi mdi-close"></i>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                     <button>Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={handlemodal} className="modal-btn">Open 
Modal</button>
         
    </>
)
} 

root.render(<App />);
```

Try out this example - https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/modal-close-button-69711607