# React - Proper way to render dynamic content?

Tags: reactjs, state, dynamic-content

I want to make a modal view has dynamic content by injecting a component to it.

```
class RootView extends Component {
    state = {
        modalBody: null
    }

    setModalBody = (body) => {
        this.setState({modalBody: body})
    }

    render() {
        return(<ContextProvider value={this.setModalBody}><Modal>{this.state.modalBody}</Modal></ContextProvider>)
    }
}
```

Then inside any children view i use `setState` to change parent `modalBody`

The `modalBody` can be setted on each route, which means the `modalBody` can be `input` list, `selection` list or text only. So the `modalBody` must have its state for controlling these inputs.

By this way, it renders ok, but the dynamic content couldn't be updated after state changed. The parent's dynamic content couldn't receive the ChildView new state, i have to `setModalBody` again and again after it rerendered.

For example, if input in modalBody has changed, the parent couldn't be updated.

```
class ChildView extends Component {
    state = {
        inputValue: null
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})
    }


    setModalBody(body) {
        this.props.context.setModalBody(<input value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />)
    }

    render() {
        return(<Modal>{this.state.modalBody}</Modal>)
    }
}
```

Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/lp5p20mx1m
Any proper way to render dynamic content to parent?

Comment: try [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need to create a parent `Modal` component, when you can make the `Modal` a simple reusable `child` component.

**See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836921/close-react-modal/55838921#55838921) for a detailed explanation on how to achieve a stateful parent that controls a child modal.**

---

However, if you MUST have a parent `Modal` component, then you can create a `render prop` to pass down `props` to be used by its `children`.

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Parent Modal]

**components/Modal.js** (`parent` component -- this has a lot of smaller components that were separated for reusability and ease of understanding -- they're basically simple `div`s with some `styles` attached -- see notes below)

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import BackgroundOverlay from "../BackgroundOverlay"; // grey background
import ClickHandler from "../ClickHandler"; // handles clicks outside of the modal
import Container from "../Container"; // contains the modal and background
import Content from "../Content"; // renders the "children" placed inside of <Modal>...</Modal>
import ModalContainer from "../ModalContainer"; // places the modal in the center of the page


class Modal extends Component {
  state = { isOpen: false };

  handleOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };


  // this is a ternary operator (shorthand for "if/else" -- if cond ? then : else)
  // below can be read like: if isOpen is true, then render the modal,
  // else render whatever the child component is returning (in this case,
  // initially returning an "Open Modal" button)
  render = () =>
    this.state.isOpen ? (
      <Container>
        <BackgroundOverlay />
        <ModalContainer>
          <ClickHandler
            isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
            closeModal={this.handleCloseModal}
          >
            <Content>
              {this.props.children({
                isOpen: this.state.isOpen,
                onCloseModal: this.handleCloseModal,
                onOpenModal: this.handleOpenModal
              })}
            </Content>
          </ClickHandler>
        </ModalContainer>
      </Container>
    ) : (
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.children({
          isOpen: this.state.isOpen,
          onCloseModal: this.handleCloseModal,
          onOpenModal: this.handleOpenModal
        })}
      </Fragment>
    );
}

// these proptype declarations are to ensure that passed down props are 
// consistent and are defined as expected
Modal.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired // children must be a function
};

export default Modal;
```

**components/Example.js** (`child` component accepting `isOpen`, `onCloseModal` and `onOpenModal` from the `parent` -- with this approach, as you'll notice, there's duplicate `isOpen` logic. While this approach gives you full control over the parent, it's repetitive. However, you can simplify your components by moving the "Open Modal" button logic to the parent, and passing in a prop like `<Modal btnTitle="Open Modal">` to make it somewhat flexible, **BUT** you'll still lose some control of what's being initially rendered when `isOpen` is `false`.)

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import "./styles.css";

const Example = () => (
  <div className="example">
    <h2>Parent Modal Example</h2>
    <Modal>
      {({ isOpen, onCloseModal, onOpenModal }) =>
        isOpen ? (
          <Fragment>
            <h1 className="title">Hello!</h1>
            <p className="subtitle">There are two ways to close this modal</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Click outside of this modal in the grey overlay area.</li>
              <li>Click the close button below.</li>
            </ul>
            <button
              className="uk-button uk-button-danger uk-button-small"
              onClick={onCloseModal}
            >
              Close
            </button>
          </Fragment>
        ) : (
          <button
            className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small"
            onClick={onOpenModal}
          >
            Open Modal
          </button>
        )
      }
    </Modal>
  </div>
);

export default Example;
```

Comment: I want dynamic contents, not static, it mean the `Modal` in parent component is only a wrapper, the ModalBody can be setted on each route, which means the modal body can be `input` list, `selection` list or text only. So the modal body must have it own state for controlling these input type, which can be done by passing it to the parent one. Child state changed, but parent state couldn't update. Close and hide is the standard method, i've done it.

Comment: Please read again. The content is not static. The modal renders whatever content you pass into it. You can render a child `class` component with `state` if desired. You can also pass `props` into the parent via `<Modal prop={prop}>`. Again, it's a reusable component. If this isn't what you want, then please provide a mvce: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (codesandbox would be ideal).

Comment: I've read your code, it's static, because you imported ALL your modal types to use inside `Example` you have only four types of content: `Modal, Hello, Form, List`. Then if i want Example to render other complex components with `selection box, input` combined, i have to import it before using it?!. Dynamic content means it will be passed without knowing what it is dynamically, the component is generated from any child component, any type to use without importing it from parent component.

Comment: You don't have to `import` a child component to display it. You can define `children` inline. The only thing you need to import is the reusable `Modal` or `SimpleModal` parent component and utilize it within a `component`. For example, I've updated the codesandbox to include a `SimpleForm` component that defines a `form` inline. That said, if your goal is to generate this `SimpleForm` on-the-fly, I don't think that is possible and/or not practical. Also, the modal shouldn't be aware of child state. The modal should only be concerned with opening and closing.

Comment: You can test my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/lp5p20mx1m this is dynamic content. Modal content from root view can be inject anywhere, anytime. You reused WHOLE modal - i'm doing it two and i think it will have more duplicate code so i want any child view to inherit Modal wrapper from root view without doing more wasted code like show/hide modal.... only one Modal INSTANCE for one the app.

Comment: Reusable components are easier to manage. One modal instance shared across your entire application seems unnecessary and problematic as your application grows in structure. In your case, your `input` loses context of `this` when "injected" into your modal. This is why UI Frameworks, like ant-design: https://ant.design/components/modal/, Material UI: https://material-ui.com/utils/modal/ and bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/ utilize reusable components. I get what you're trying to do, but it just doesn't have any benefits and overcomplicates your components.

Comment: Working example of your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6j9wkwkqo3. Child components must be separate, imported and maintained by their own state. The biggest problem you'll run into is when `child` becomes deeply nested. You'll have to pass down `setModalContent` to EVERY child (and their children's children... and so on). Lastly, as shown in the sandbox, your `child` component will contain `WET code`.

Comment: I don't have to pass anything, i'm using Context. So in every child level, it can access to the root view to open modal directly. Modal is one of the global instances. It avoids creating multiple instance of modal and duplicate code. I know if i separate modal content to new component with its state, it works, but don't know why it doesn't work if i use state inside `Child.js` component. Btw, I would accept your answer and appreciate your help

Comment: Your passed in element loses context of `this` when it's sent to the `parent` modal's callback function. By bundling it as a `component`, it becomes self-contained. HOWEVER, you can update the `component/pure function` with props, although, it's this approach is hacky and I don't recommend it: https://codesandbox.io/s/4307lp800. Again, your modal should only be concerned with opening/closing and rendering `children`.